# format json errors in Laravel when validation fails

Tags: json, laravel, api, validation, custom-errors

I'm new to Laravel. I'm trying to create an API post request. This is the validation I have.

```
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'started_date' => 'required|after:2012-01-01|before:tomorrow',
    ]);
```

When the validation fails, with the validation I have, let's say "name" and "started_date" are missing, this is the response I get.

```
{
 "message": "The given data was invalid.",
 "errors": {
    "name": [
        "The name field is required."
    ],
    "started_date": [
        "The started date must be a date before tomorrow."
    ]
}
```

However, It's not the format I want. Here is what I want

```
 {
 "message": "The given data was invalid.",
 "errors": {
    "name": "The name field is required.",
    "started_date": "The started date must be a date before tomorrow."
}
```

So what should I do to format the response?

Comment: Did you think about why the structure above exists? What are you going to do if an attribute has multiple errors like this: `"name": [ "The name field is required.","Some other error.","Another one", ]`, now you cannot simply do the desired transformation. Please explain why you want it to look diffrent?

Comment: I think the structure above exists beacuse, for example, name can have multiple conditions. I want it to look differrent because it will make it easy for the front-end app. I don't think I need to show multiple error messages

Comment: Just use the first element in the array? errors.name[0]

Comment: I think this can be an option to go with